# Change the color of a specific word in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have seen multiple articles about this topic but none of them helped in my case and most of them were for Excel. I want to change the font color using `vba` code in word. I have tried `Selection.Font.Color` but it didn't work either. I know that `vba` needs a variable which have that particular word but I'm failing on doing this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I used a workaround to replace the font color of a word using this `vba` code

```vb
With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "hello"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "hi"
        .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorBlack 'I added this line
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
         Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
```

But I was looking to more a specific way to **replace** the font color of a word in vba.

Comment: `Selection` depends on what you have selected.... Perhaps you can include a bit more context? Maybe post the code you are using?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that with this code 
```
  With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        Selection.Font.Color = wdColorWhite
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True
    End With
```
I could change the color if the word was `highlighted` but i dont want the word to be highlighted to change color

Comment: Then you need to decide what other method you will use to tell Word which part to change. Have you done any more research? There a tons of different options that would be pointless to try and explain to you in an answer.

Comment: for example here is a sentence "from black to green" and then using vba it should be like: sentence = from black to green" 

Selection.Font.Color = wdColorWhite

Comment: @braX as explained in my question i have seem multiple options but they all were for excel. If you know many solution you can be my guest and make an answer to this question

Comment: I dont think you understand what i am saying. If you don't want it selected, then you cannot use `Selection` at all. For example, you can change the color of an entire paragraph just be referencing that object.

Comment: im a novice to vba that's why I asked for help. If I'd know the solution I wouldn't be here with you discussing.

Comment: `selection.Font.Color=vbred` (for example) works fine, so it's not clear what the exact problem is?  Maybe you could explain a little more what you're trying to do.   What exactly is it that you need to color?   All instances of a specific word/phrase or ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I know that `selection.Font.Color=vbred` works just fine but when the `cursor` or *that specific* word has been `highlighted` but I wanted to replace the font color of a word in the document. Which I found a workaround. I have this `VBA` code to replace a word with another (from "hello" to "hi") and used `.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorBlack` inside the `With Selection.Find` (function?).

Comment: So you're all set?

Comment: @TimWilliams I guess so but i was looking to a way to spend less lines, you know what I mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a re-usable piece of code then something like this should be close:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    ActiveDocument.Content.Font.Color = vbBlack
    
    ColorText ActiveDocument.Content, "breaks", vbRed
    ColorText ActiveDocument.Content, "it", vbBlue
    ColorText ActiveDocument.Content, "with just", vbGreen

End Sub


Sub ColorText(rng As Range, strFind As String, clr As Long)
    With rng.Find
        .Text = strFind
        .Forward = True
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        Do While .Execute()
            rng.Font.Color = clr 'rng is redefined as the found text
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop to replace the color when it can be done using FnR? Just look back at the code in the question for the correct code.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - because I didn't know any better?

Comment: Recording a macro would have given you the syntax. You need to set `.Format = True` then replace the loop with `.Replacement.Font.Color = clr` followed by `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop`